# How to position UIScrollView behing the keyboard when the orientation changes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, keyboard, orientation

I have a `UIScrollView` designed to enable scrolling when the keyboard is up. The positioning of the scroll view is fine in portrait mode; I have positioned it in Interface Builder, and set the `contentSize` in my code ...

```
CGSize scrollContentSize = CGSizeMake(360, 221);
self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentSize;
```

However, I am struggling to work out how to change the position of the `scrollview` so it works effectively when the orientation changes to landscape (and back). Do I somehow need to position it in Interface Builder for landscape(?), and then change the content size in my code dependent on the orientation?

Edit:
Im getting the keyboard size as follows, and changing the content size. This works when i move to Portrait, but the frame is positioned slightly wrong in landscape mode.

```
 (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)n{

    if (keyboardIsShown) {
    return;
    }

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [n userInfo];

    CGRect _keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&_keyboardEndFrame];
    CGFloat _keyboardHeight;
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    _keyboardHeight = _keyboardEndFrame.size.height;
    }
    else {
        _keyboardHeight = _keyboardEndFrame.size.width;
    }

    // resize the noteView
    CGRect viewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
     viewFrame.size.height -= _keyboardHeight;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)){
        CGSize scrollContentSize = CGSizeMake(360, 221);
        self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentSize;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)){
        CGSize scrollContentSize = CGSizeMake(520, 275);
        self.scrollView.contentSize = scrollContentSize;
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.scrollView setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    keyboardIsShown = YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the contentSize you want to change, and not the frame of the scrollView?  I imagine you want to shrink the frame to accommodate the keyboard.  Is my assumption correct?

Comment: That is very possibly where I am confused, yes. Or maybe I need to change both.

Comment: You should handle the standard keyboard notifications to get the actual size of the keyboard. When you switch orientations, you will receive keyboard notifications again telling you the new size.

Comment: I've tried that Mike but its not quite working. ive added this code to my question above. Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly the height of my navigation bar needs to be removed from my frame origin.y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is figure out the where the top of the keyboard is relative to the view that contains your scrollView.  Fortunately, there is a function in UIView called `convertRect:fromView:` that will take the frame from one coordinate system and map it to another coordinate system.  In your case, you know the frame of the keyboard relative to the main window, but would like to know where the top of the keyboard is relative to the view that contains your scrollView.  Once you know where the top of the keyboard intersects with your view, you can modify the height of your scrollView to accommodate.

Below is a snippet of code I use, which I found somewhere online and don't take credit for.  In your view controller you want to be notified of keyboard show and hide events:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then implement `keyboardWillShow:` and `keyboardWillHide:` like this:

```
// When the keyboard shows resize self.textView to touch the top of the keyboard.
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)_notification {
    NSDictionary  *userInfo = [_notification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

        // Here we figure out where the keyboard overlaps with self.view
        // self.view contains self.textView
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame fromView:nil];
    CGFloat textViewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, textViewWidth, keyboardFrame.origin.y);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// When the keyboard hides return self.textView to fullscreen
-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)_notification {
    NSDictionary  *userInfo = [_notification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    self.textView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

The snippet contains some extra stuff to animate the transition in sync with the keyboard animation.

In this snippet I use `self.textView`, which you will probably want to change to `self.scrollView`.  What's great about this code is that it works in all orientations and on the iPad.  Take a look at the code and hopefully it'll be self explanatory.

Comment: Chris, this is absolutely fantastic. The only issue I currently can see though, is that, in portrait mode, my onscreen stuff isn't stretching all the way left and right, meaning that I can scroll left and right when I don't want to be able to. Possibly this is because of the co-ordinates Im setting for my scrollView.contentSize (the first bit of code Ive pasted into my question above), but Im not sure yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Aha! I've managed to stop any width-ways scrolling by making my contentSize CGSizeMake(0, 221). However, now Ive noticed that if I press the back button, then return to my screen, it has broken. But Im getting close!

Comment: Correction: Ive made it  CGSizeMake(160, 221), because  CGSizeMake(1, 221) stopped the view from scrolling down when a lower textView was selected. I dont know why.

Comment: Ok, Ive fixed the back button problem. I needed to make a new contentSize if it starts in landscape mode. The only problem I have now is, if the keyboard is down and I click on a low down textField, the keyboard pops up over the textField, rather than scrolling down to the textView like it normally does.

Comment: When I click on a textField, it gets covered by the keyboard, but when i start typing it scrolls up.

Comment: This now works. I got th etext field frame with this -(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textFieldRect = [textField frame];
} and then scolled to it with this     [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textFieldRect animated:YES];

Comment: You should be able to do this without hard coding any values.  Your contentSize should be calculated from its subviews.

Comment: Mmm. Not Ive been working on this stuff for a while, I understand a bit more. Thinking aloud here, maybe I need to make the contentSize the view size minus the keyboard. I'll need to play with this more to get it done properly.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to check orientation & change content Size of scrollView according to orientation

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

Comment: i guess ,you need to change frame ie. position of scrollView

Comment: Im trying          self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 110, 360, 220); (using the figures that inteface builder has for the portrait scroll view) but it moves the scroll view somewhere different. Maybe Im doing something silly?